# Arabic Calendar (Arabic Datetimepicker) In C# Winform Application

Tags: c#, winforms, datepicker, hijri

I have created a form and I need to add the Hijri date to it.
How can I add Arabic Calendar (Hijri Datetimepicker) In the C# Winform Application?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Syncfusion or Telerik components

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).